# Can Room bulk Insert return List<T> for inserted values with Conflict Strategy IGNORE?

Tags: android, android-room

Android Room bulk `@Insert` can return a `List<Long>` of the inserted data `RowId`'s.

Is it possible if my @Entity has a `String` Primary key to have a Bulk insert statement return a `List<String>`'s containing the inserted String values when using the Conflict Strategy IGNORE?

When I try this code

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
 fun insertIgnore(data: ArrayList<MyDO>): List<String>
```

I get this build error message:-

```
error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
```

Comment: are you using livedata, also post your library versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it expects to return an array of longs (the rowid's of the inserted rows) not the objects being inserted.

The values will be 1 or greater if the insert was successful.

You can correlate these via the index to the array that was passed and thus determine the respective object's values that were or were not inserted.

e.g. (java rather than Kotlin) :-

using

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
long[] addDrinks(DrinkList... drinkLists);
```

you can use :-

```
    long[] result = mDrinkListDao.addDrinks(drinksToAdd);
    for (int i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] > 0) {
            Log.d("INSERTRESULT",drinksToAdd[i].getList() + "was inserted.");
        } else {
            Log.d("INSERTRESULT", drinksToAdd[i].getList() + "was not inserted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, it helps a lot.

ps: if you use kotlin you can use LongArray

example: 
@Insert
suspend fun insertUserList(userList: List<UserEntity>): LongArray